# Custom post feed for iOS - current post offset

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, pagination, lazy-loading

I'm trying to make some custom `feed` with `posts` of `image` and `titles` and currently I'm doing it for mobile. I'm using PHP for webservice.

When using `pagination` how do you download `posts` from web? Do you send some `page` parameter to `webservice` or is there some other way?

So something like this:

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/?command=stream&page=0
```

and then just increment `page` that is private variable in-app and autoincremented before every new request? Or this is done in a different way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track. The usual practice is to send a *currentOffset*, or a *page number* parameter (if your entries per page is constant).

I am assuming you want to display the feed in a UITableView, and lazy-load more entries (the next page of entries) when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list. You can implement the pagination logic yourself by implementing scrollViewDidScroll: to detect that you have hit the bottom of the list, but I find [NMPaginator](https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator) particularly helpful for this purpose.